# error when preforming correspondence analysis in R

Tags: r, correspondence-analysis

I am new to Correspondence analysis and to R.
I have the following dataset:
[image: data]

```
df <- read.table(text = "
word daruri lazim
means 9130 55744
Intentionally-act 6753 32715
cure 4686 17136
statement 568 8341
money 1565 20860
response 0 7661
expertise 1925 12483
supporting 635 12394
gizmo 1884 11562
Terms_of_agreement 0 7492
inspecting 514 9542
Locale_by_use 311 4900
ARRANGING 310 7772
documents 795 12160
DYNAMISM 578 7093
information 6562 9830
ACTIVITY_PREPARE 1247 4809
protecting 1540 6404
LIKELIHOOD 451 3068
ASSISSTANCE 0 3493
ACTIVITY_on_GOING 1743 2498
BEING-NECESSARY 6987 2507
Deny_or_grant_permission 0 3858
Source_of_getting 810 3686
deciding 0 4796
needing 13498 4955
supply 0 2292
Cause_change 1709 2714
timespan 0 9227
capability 0 3565
Public_services 5362 5092
reassuring 515 1895
Criminal_investigation 0 3888
Attempt_suasion 465 1769
education 0 6008
project 0 2581
attention 0 2190
remove 0 2955
qunatity 0 2244
law 325 1751
Resolve_problem 0 2540
substance 2754 3799
experimentation 0 3155
awareness 0 1610
Objective_influence 0 1200
effort 0 1973
entity 6927 2554
Reforming_a_system 1839 1137
control 0 1229
food 2021 1752
Level_of_force_resistance 0 978
Quantified_mass 434 1149
importance 1364 864
Speed_description 0 983
WORK 0 4203
contracts 0 1214
Take_place_of 0 740
topic 24346 2276
condition 5682 0
buying 2989 0
element 3357 0
premise 1418 0
assistance 1661 0
being 1628 0
questioning 1048 0
essential 702 0
surrender 208 0
health 437 0", header = TRUE)
```

I want to perform simple correspondence analysis. I used the FactoMineR package, using the command CA:

```
CA(filename) -> re.filename
```

The results show up like this:

[image: results]

Then I want to see the visual representation of these results. I used the package factoextra, using the command fviz_ca_biplot

I get the error:

```
Error in if (max(axes) > ndim) stop("The value of the argument axes is incorrect. ",  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Can you please tell me what to do to get this done for my paper?

I also tried other packages, but they always come back with different errors.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I added the dataset as text.